# Google Analytics user_id appended to links

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Google Analytics now has UserID tracking to better track individual users across devices. Is it possible to add a tracking variable (like utm_campaign) specifying **user_ID** so that GA will associate those links with the user?

I'm looking for a solution that'll work even when the **user isn't logged in** (mainly for email link tracking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Of course you can append the user id yourself and set it in your tracking code. But that would not uniquely identify a user (links get bookmarked or passed around e.g. when the email is forwareded to somebody) and someone else might end up with that id. The idea of the user id is that the CMS or CRM takes responsibilty for uniquely identifying users so we don't have to rely on the somewhat fragile client side mechanisms.

If you use it for email tracking it should IMO be enough if the user id is set in the first call of the tracking code if you have [session unification](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4574780?hl=en) enabled, so you'd just need to tag the link in the mail and read the id from there, without needing to persists the user id via the links. While I haven't tested this extensively the documentation seems clear on the point:

> Session unification is a User ID setting that allows hits collected
>   before the User ID is assigned to be associated with the ID, so long
>   as those hits happen within the same session in which a specific ID
>   value is assigned for the first time.

Please note that the user id feature does not expose data for individual users via the interface, insofar the idea that it "better track[s] individual users" is not quite right (it will recognize users across devices but will still aggregate the data). If you want individual user you need to store the user id (or some other unique id) as custom dimension.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Session unification, that pretty much meets my needs.